# How is this nested loop algorithm analyzed?

Tags: algorithm, analysis

So i have this algorithm analysis from my lecturer i need some help why the outer loop is n - 1 , isn't it should be n - 2? and the inner loop should be log3 (n) instead of log3(n) + 1

```
for(int a=3; a<=n; a++)                 n+1-2 = n-1
      
      for(int a=1; a<n; a=a*3)          log3 (n) +1

          System.out.println(a);         log3 (n)
```

Total    =(n - 1)* (log3 (n)+1+log3 (n))

```
     =(n-1)*(2 log3(n) + 1)

     =2(n log3(n))+n -1 – 2 log3(n)

     =n log3(n) + n – log3(n)
```

Is this correct answer for algorithmn analysis? thats what my lecturer showed me. Anyone can explain to me?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a very precise count of the operations, it's important to specify: what operations are you counting? Number of increments `a++`? Number of comparisons `a<=n`? Number of executions of the loop body?

If you don't specify which operation you're counting, then there is not much sense in worrying about an extra +1 or -1.

Note that the variable used as counter for the outer loop is called `a` and the variable used as counter for the inner loop is also called `a`. While this is possible to do in C++, I strongly recommend not doing it. It's confusing and a good source of errors.

The outer loop is going to run for n-2 iterations. The inner loop is going to run for ceil(log3(n)) iterations (where ceil is [the ceiling function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions)). The line `System.out.println(a)` is not a loop, it's just one line of code, so you could write "1" on that line if you wanted; there is not much sense in writing "log3(n)" here.

The total number of times the line `System.out.println(a)` is executed is thus:

**(n - 2) ceil(log3(n))**.

It is possible that you might want to count the exact number of characters written. Again, we're coming back to the fact that you didn't specify what it is that you were counting. The number of characters depends on the exact value of `a`, so it changes at each iteration of the loop. But all in all, each call to `System.out.println(a)` prints about log10(n) characters, since we're writing in decimal.